# How do I execute a sudo command without password and without specifying path?

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo, bashrc

I have a directory with scripts: /etc/scripts.

Now I want to execute the scripts like: `sudo scriptname`
without having to provide a password or having to specify the path to the script.

I added /etc/scripts to the $PATH variable:

```
/etc/scripts:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

and have also added the different paths to these scripts to the bottom of my sudoers file like:

```
steven ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/etc/scripts/dns_add_zone,/etc/scripts/dns_add_record
```

So executing the script like `sudo /etc/scripts/scriptname` works but not without specifying the path.

Comment: You added it only to your path, not in roots path which `sudo` uses.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I now also added it to roots path but I'm still getting asked for a password.

Comment: It's actually the sudoers `secure_path` that's relevant here - personally, I'd avoid `/etc` for scripts and instead place them in `/usr/local/sbin`, which is already in the `secure_path`

Comment: Thank you! that solved it.

Comment: @steven please consider "accepting" the answer (check the mark on the left of the question) to show your appreciation to the author and help future readers find the good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu, `sudo` is configured to search for programs in its own `secure_path`, defined in the `/etc/sudoers` file, rather than either the invoking user's or target (root) user's `PATH`:

```
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"
```

If you want it to find programs in /etc/scripts, you would need to add that directory to the `secure_path`. However you might want to consider using one of the locations that is already on the `secure_path` such as `/usr/local/sbin`  - which would be more consistent with the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).

Comment: Except it never made any sense to put scripts in "bin" (since they're not binaries). But that's another matter. :-)